# retrieve non built-in functions in python

Tags: python

The "dir()" function in python retrieves all attributes for a class. I was wondering if there was a similar function that returns only user defined functions? Thanks!

Comment: Can you give an example of what attributes you don't want to see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to tell a builtin from a user-defined function I'd use the [types](http://docs.python.org/library/types.html) module.
For instance:

```
>>> def hello():
...     print("hi")
... 
>>> import types
>>> type(hello) is types.BuiltinFunctionType
False
>>> type(hello) is types.FunctionType
True
```

Then it depends on what you want to do.You could use list comprehensions to check all attributes of a class and keep only those that turn out to be true.

```
[ x for x in dir(yourclass) if (type(x) is types.FunctionType) ]
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Superb! This is perfect. tks!